# Seeking TopoJSON map of Chinese provinces which includes Hong Kong, Macau and Taiwan?

Tags: data, topojson, china

I have a TopoJSON map of China which is working well in d3.js. However, it is essential that I add Hong Kong, Macau/Macao and Taiwan to the map, but they are not included in the TopoJSON file. I have been trying to add features to the map using JavaScript by editing the `arcs` property and the `geometries` directly, but nothing seems to work. The error messages from TopoJSON are not helpful because the file with the TopoJSON information is minified.

Is there a TopoJSON map of Chinese provinces which includes these three regions?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a map but I was able to upload the topojson file to a site called `geojson.io`, then I could draw on the new features by hand, download the resulting map and use it in place of the old one.